# how to upload pdf file on flutter to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I'm just a newbie in flutter and mysql, I don't know where to start, if anyone knows how to make it please explain. Thank You!!

I hope someone can help make this page simple or something. and that really helps me thank you!!

Comment: Start by breaking down the problem into smaller parts.  Are you wanting to upload the file from a mobile phone to a server? Do you already have the server side working that can receive the file and store it in the mysql database?

Comment: thanks for the reply.. yea i want to upload file from my phone to flutter then connect to mysql database. I think I understand the steps, but how do I find the file in local storage and then upload it to the database? and it seems i have created a file in htdocs to save in mysql..

Comment: The file_picker package looks very popular - https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

Comment: woaa.. i just know that, thankyou sir!!

Answer (score 0):

The easy and proper way will be -

1. Create your own `API` for your project/server to connect with
   flutter app.
2. Use `file_picker` to select one or multiple files from local storage.

> Use `syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer` or related package to view pdf(if
> needed)

3. Use `http` to upload your files to the server within `API`.

Comment: woaa.. very thank u!! i'll try that..